# getting readscript error when running botium-cli (Botium)

Tags: botium-box

I am trying out botium-cli for the first time and I am unable to run the sample script. I get the following error:

```html
xxxx-MacBook-Pro:Botium xxxxx$ npx botium-cli run --convos .
/Users/xxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:2772
                throw err;
                ^

BotiumError: ReadScript - an error occurred at 'node_modules/accepts/HISTORY.md' file: "*" not expected here (Line 4): expecting parent "##" for "*"
    at botiumErrorFromErr (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/BotiumError.js:85:12)
    at ScriptingProvider.ReadScript (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:522:13)
    at /Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:452:71
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at ScriptingProvider.ReadScriptsFromDirectory (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:451:14)
    at /Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-cli/src/run/index.js:109:14
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at handler (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-cli/src/run/index.js:108:15)
    at Object.builder.handler (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-cli/bin/botium-cli.js:34:7)
    at Object.runCommand (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/yargs/build/index.cjs:446:48) {
  context: {
    err: Error: "*" not expected here (Line 4): expecting parent "##" for "*"
        at _toStructuredMarkdown (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerMarkdown.js:55:19)
        at CompilerMarkdown.Compile (/Users/xxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/CompilerMarkdown.js:70:24)
        at ScriptingProvider.Compile (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:407:21)
        at ScriptingProvider.ReadScript (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:515:31)
        at /Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:452:71
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at ScriptingProvider.ReadScriptsFromDirectory (/Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-core/src/scripting/ScriptingProvider.js:451:14)
        at /Users/xxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-cli/src/run/index.js:109:14
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at handler (/Users/xxxxx/Desktop/Botium/node_modules/botium-cli/src/run/index.js:108:15),
    message: `ReadScript - an error occurred at 'node_modules/accepts/HISTORY.md' file: "*" not expected here (Line 4): expecting parent "##" for "*"`
  }
}
```

Steps I took to run:

- botium-cli init
- botium-cli run

specs:

- OSX Big Sur 11.2 (M1 mac)
- node v14.15.4
- botium-cli v1.0.4

Am I missing something or do I need a specific version of node?

Comment: figured out the issue. By default botium-cli creates a convo file in the root directory  and botium-cli seems to traverse all files and folders within root. Since I have node_modules within root as well, botium was trying to parse the .md files within node_modules folder. Fixed this by putting the convo file within a separate folder

Answer (score 0):

By default, Botium CLI will traverse the current directory for files that it considers to contain test cases. There are plenty of file formats supported by Botium - text, markdown, excel, csv, json, yaml and even custom formats (see [Botium Docs for more information](https://botium-docs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/05_botiumscript/index.html#supported-file-formats)).

You can come around this issue by:

- Place your test case files into another directory, suggested is to name it *tests* or *spec*, and use the *--spec* command line argument to Botium CLI to point to this directory that **contains test files only**.
- Botium also respects a **.gitignore file** - so if you place the node_modules folder within a .gitignore file, it  should work as well